# Android Studio Bluetooth InputStream - receiving float data from arduino

Tags: java, android, arduino, bluetooth, type-conversion

I am sending float data from AnalogInput - `SerialBT.print(vArduino);` via Bluetooth to my Android Studio app.
I am getting data in bytes, struggling how to get them in float or at least convert them to float to make calculations. Can I use ObjectInputStream, how?

Java Code:

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    inputStream = btSocket.getInputStream();
                    inputStream.skip(inputStream.available());

                    
                    byte b = (byte) inputStream.read();
                    System.out.println((char) b);
                }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Solution - reading float value

```
DataInputStream inputStream = null;
                try {

                    DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(btSocket.getInputStream());
                    float d = input.readFloat();
                  
                     System.out.println(d);
                   

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Problem: im expecting V ~0.00 - 1.50, Later up to 55.00
While ~0.00, it prints 6.336931E-10,
~1.05 - 2.53483E-9

When I changed values to double in Arduino and Android Studio, I cant read the value from

```
double d = inputStream.readDouble();
```

Error:

```
W/System.err: at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.read(BluetoothSocket.java:606) W/System.err: at android.bluetooth.BluetoothInputStream.read(BluetoothInputStream.java:88) W/System.err: at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:198) W/System.err: at java.io.DataInputStream.readLong(DataInputStream.java:413) W/System.err: at java.io.DataInputStream.readDouble(DataInputStream.java:465) at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$ExampleRunnable.run(MainActivity.java:153) W/System.err: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
```

I tried to doing this "manually" - successfully, getting values from array and stickly setting them in sequence to String, and then to double value, but i don't know, is it a good way to do like this.

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    inputStream = btSocket.getInputStream();
                    inputStream.skip(inputStream.available());
                    char[] byteArray = new char[4];
                    String voltageString = "";

                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                        char b = (char) inputStream.read();
                        byteArray[i]=b;
                        voltageString += b;


                    }
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(byteArray));
                   
                    double voltage = Double.parseDouble(voltageString);
                    System.out.println(voltage);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

In this case, the output values are the same as i wanted, i need only 0.00-60.0, one decimal point is missing, if the value is between 10-100 because of for loop, but that's even better in my calculations.

Comment: You should tell the value of that float and then the code to send the variable. After that tell how many bytes you receive. Also tell the value of the bytes in hexadecimal notation.

Comment: You are reading only one byte

Comment: Is it the most efficient way? Creating an array with length 4 to make float value from that bytes? Im doing this in thread till click stop

Comment: DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(btSocket.getInputStream());
                    while (input.available() > 0) {
                        float d = input.readFloat(); }       I think that its okay, but im getting 6.336931E-10

Comment: Well that is a nice float value. If you dont tell what was sent or what you expected ... And please put code and results in your post. Not in comments.

Comment: Why its getting this value instead of + 0.00 etc?

Comment: Well 6.336931E-10 is zero dont you think? A float is not precise. Can not be precise. How precise do you want it?

Comment: Should i use double then? If im doing this on double value, I dont receive any value. I set up this in arduino and Android Studio, i found a solution to make float i want, i did the array of Strings and put there this 4 characters received from InputStream with for loop, then Float.parseFloat(thisString)

Comment: ... And please put code and results in your post. Not in comments.